# How to sort and filter data.frame in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, subset

I understand how to sort a data frame:

`df[order(df$Height),]`

and I understand how to filter (or subset) a data frame matching some predicate:

`df[df$Weight > 120,]`

but how do I sort *and* filter (as an example, order by Height and filter by Weight)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either in two steps

```
 df1 <- df[df$weight > 120, ]
 df2 <- df1[order(df1$height), ]
```

or if you must in one step -- but it really is not any cleaner.

Data first:

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> df <- data.frame(weight=rnorm(10, 120, 10), height=rnorm(10, 160, 20))
R> df
   weight height
1   133.7  186.1
2   114.4  205.7
3   123.6  132.2
4   126.3  154.4
5   124.0  157.3
6   118.9  172.7
7   135.1  154.3
8   119.1  106.9
9   140.2  111.2
10  119.4  186.4
```

And one way of doing it is double-subsetting:

```
R> subset(df, weight > 120)[order(subset(df, weight > 120)$height),]
  weight height
9  140.2  111.2
3  123.6  132.2
7  135.1  154.3
4  126.3  154.4
5  124.0  157.3
1  133.7  186.1
R>
```

I'd go with the two-step.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `set.seed(42)`?

Comment: I'd use `reshape2::arrange(subset(df, weight > 120), height)`

Comment: I was waiting for the appropriate Hadley-isms :-)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel @mrdwab Of course I know. I would say why `42`, not `1` or `2`.

Comment: It's a mild cultural reference to the "Hitchhiker's Hike to the Galaxy".

Comment: ah, now I came up with `42` as the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.

Comment: @kohske here's my guess: Dirk happens to have a global `set.seed(88)` in his `.Rprofile`, then generated a random seed for SO, `s = sample(1:100, 1) ; set.seed(s)`.

Comment: @baptiste No, `42` is the answer ;-p I like it. I will follow it. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, typo above: Hitchhiker's Guide, of course.   In the larger sense, *which* seed one picks does not matter much with a good RNG for a long that *any* seed is picked to ensure reproducibility.

Comment: Good advice about preferring two-steps to one.  Readable code trumps clever code almost always.

Comment: What's the difference between using the subset function and bracket indexing?  That is, is `df[weight > 120),][order(subset(df, weight > 120)$height),]` equivalent to the expression in your answer?

Answer (score 12):

The package `data.table` allows you to this in one short line of code:

Borrowing Dirk Eddelbuettel's example, set up some data:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(weight=rnorm(10, 120, 10), height=rnorm(10, 160, 20))
```

Convert the `data.frame` to a `data.table` and subset on weight, ordering by height:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[weight>120][order(height)]

       weight   height
[1,] 140.1842 111.1907
[2,] 123.6313 132.2228
[3,] 135.1152 154.3149
[4,] 126.3286 154.4242
[5,] 124.0427 157.3336
[6,] 133.7096 186.0974
```

Comment: Nice. Yes this is one of the key convenience features of `data.table`. I wonder if new users think they have to convert all the time to use `data.table`, though? In this case, and many others, the call to `data.frame()` can be replaced by `data.table()` and there's no need to convert when starting with a `data.table` in the first place. I know you know this, it's just a marketing question really.

Answer (score 8):

```
df1 <- df[order(df$height), ][df$weight > 120, ]
```

Just make sure to put the order before the filter.

Comment: Not working for me:  I get `$weight`s in the answer less than 120.